# Are conditioning and marginalizing adjoint?

Tags: pr.probability

I have been curious about this for a long time.  Is there a sensible notion of a conditional random variable?  I have been told "no" before, but I don't feel that I ever got a clear answer.  And, in fact, I see them get used in statistics all the time.  In particular, $x \sim (X|Y)$ is shorthand for

$$y\sim Y\\ x\sim (X|Y=y).$$

This "sample and bind" shorthand seems completely straight-forward to me, since we can "always" recover the distribution of $Y$ from the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ by marginalizing $X$ out.  Are marginalizing and conditioning adjoints?  It seems that the notation witnesses triple-ability, if they are adjoint at all.

Comment: In terms of the probability behind this, you should look up disintegrations and regular conditional probabilities. I don't know about the categorial side of the question.